# How can I append text to a databound field?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview, string, image

If I have this:

```
<img ID="imgField" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name") %>' />
```

How can I add "images/" or any other string add on to the url?

I tried

```
ImageUrl=' "images/" + <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name") %>'
```

And

```
ImageUrl= "images/" + '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name") %>'
```

And

```
ImageUrl='images/<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name") %>'
```

But none of them worked. Anyone know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<img ID="imgField" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# string.Format("images/{0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name")) %>' />
```

Or, if you want to shorten it up a bit...

```
<img ID="imgField" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# string.Format("images/{0}", Eval("Name")) %>' />
```

and I think this should work too - but don't have a project in front of me to test it on...

```
<img ID="imgField" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Name", "images/{0}") %>' />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<img ID="imgField" runat="server"
  ImageUrl='<%# "images/" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name") %>' />
```

Or inside a gridview, you could use an ImageField column:

```
<asp:GridView>
  <Columns>
    <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Name"
      DataImageUrlFormatString="images/{0}" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were using 
   <%
instead of the correct:
   <%#

Comment: You're correct about needing the #, however I did already have it in my application, I just didn't write it in my example. Thanks!